# What does .once(string, function) do?

Tags: gulp

I am analyzing the VS Code tests.

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('test/all.js')
        .pipe(mocha({ ui: 'tdd', delay: true }))
        .once('end', function () { process.exit(); });
});
```

I have not found any documentation for `once(string, function)`. What does it do? Where are the docs?

[Having searched the gulp source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=once%28&type=) reveals the use of but not the definition of once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`once()` is a feature/function of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) not Gulp.

[Here's the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener).

In `Streams`, it can be used to add a one time `listener`. Once the `event` is triggered, the `listener` is invoked and removed.